# How to make some menus visible for only logged in users in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu

How do I make some menus visible for only logged in users in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use WordPress' is_user_logged_in() function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion , but how can I use this function along with wordpress nav , I am really confused .

Comment: Drop the function above into your theme's template file(s). For example, to show a WP menu to logged in users only, you could use something along the lines of <?php if (is_logged_in()) { wp_nav_menu(); } ?>

Comment: Thanks , but how can I show a particular menu only for logined users.Let us consider I have 2 menus named outer and inner . Then how can I show the inner menu only for logined users using that concept ?

Comment: Pass the name of the menu into the function's arguments. wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu Name Goes Here' )) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Great Support , Thanks

Comment: It all depends on where you want your menu to go and how your theme is structured, but I guess it would be header.php if you want the menu to appear at the top of all pages.